# Do I require a UK visa when I already have a Schengen multiple entry 3 year visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, standard-visitor-visas

My partner is a UK citizen and I want to visit London and other parts of the UK to see him and his children from time to time, from South Africa, so I already have a 3 year Schengen visa for this very reason but now flying to London from South Africa  on the 22nd of July until the 7th of August and in-between my visit i will be going to Spain for a few days and back to London to fly back home to SA.

How  do i get a multiple entry Uk visa so that I can visit the Uk more often on my trips to the rest of Europe?

I would not like to apply for a UK visa each time I go to the Uk and London, is this possible like I did with the Schengen visa?

Comment: Not sure I understand why you have a Schengen visa "to visit London and other parts of the UK"? Schengen and UK visas are completely independent.

Comment: Welcome to Travel! You seem to have a different question in your title as in your question body. It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: If you are married to your partner, you should look into an [EEA family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/overview).

Answer (score 3):

**How do i get a multiple entry Uk visa so that I can visit the Uk more often on my trips to the rest of Europe?**

All "Standard Visitor Visas" are multiple entry by default. You can come and go multiple times. Of course you have a landing interview upon arrival where you state your premise.

**I would not like to apply for a UK visa each time I go to the Uk and London, is this possible like I did with the Schengen visa?**

The visa is issued for 6 months.  They will not issue a 2 or 5 year visa until you have lots of experience with the 6 month visa and they classify you as a bona fide visitor.  Also, you need a strong premise to get the 2 or 5 year visitor visa, it cannot be just a matter of personal convenience.

Having a Schengen visa is of negligible value to the UK. Schengen is not officially recognized by the government (except for agreements to share information).

---

To apply for a Standard Visitor Visa, you can open an account at [Visa4UK](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/home/welcome) and fill out the application. Based on everything you wrote, your first screen should look be filled out like this...

[image]

It is emphatically recommended to study the [rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules) and [guidance](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) before setting out. The visitor rules are in Appendix V. We see a lot of refusal cases here that could have been avoided by reading the guidance.

Adding...

The carrier will not allow a South African to board unless their passport has an entry clearance in it.  It prevents their being fined (and prevents you from being served with a removal notice). The experience of a boarding refusal gets people upset because of the distress of wasted time and airfares, so it should be avoided by having the right visas.  There are some articles on this site where angry  people wanted to blame the carrier for selling them a ticket in the first instance, they may be worth reading.  The bottom line is that it's spelled out in the small print of the ticket's terms and conditions that *you* are responsible.